# Multiple CKEDITOR on one page asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, ckeditor

Im trying to have more than one CKEDITOR on my page, and currently only the first one will show. My code looks like this

```
     <div class="edit_row">
      <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CKEDITORFirst" TextMode="Number" />
 </div>
 <div class="edit_row">
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="CKEDITORSecond"TextMode="Number" />
 </div>
```

And javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var roxyFileman = '../fileman/index.html';
        $(function () {
            CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtSubMenuEditText.ClientID%>', {
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: roxyFileman,
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: roxyFileman + '?type=image',
                removeDialogTabs: 'link:upload;image:upload'
            });
            CKEDITOR.add
        });
        $(function ()
        {
               CKEDITOR.replace('<%=txtSubMenuNewText.ClientID%>', {
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: roxyFileman,
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: roxyFileman + '?type=image',
                removeDialogTabs: 'link:upload;image:upload'
               });

        })
</script>
```

But only the first one shows.

Anyone know how to show multiple CKEDITORS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make few lines like this with different ID's:

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor2" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

look at samples:
http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Samples